# note 3 and note 8

Tags: wifi-hotspot, samsung-galaxy-note

Are you aware of any issues with the Note 8 phones giving hot-spot access to the devices nearby if the note version you got is from another country or region? Does Samsung have restrictions still?

You may ask why I am asking such a question, and what the rationale is. 
What prompts me to this question is the following experience I got.

I used note-3 (for years while I lived in in the US. ). No issues. But, when I brought it to Turkey, and put in a TURKCELL LTE simcard, I learned that it cannot give hotspot to my devices. (Whereas the iPhone 6plus which I also used and brought from the US ) does not have this issue with the Turkish Carriers.

Now I'm about to purchase a note 8 from Dubai (to use it in Turkey with TURKCELL ).  I'd like to make sure that if I put the Turkish sim card in it, I will be able to create a hot spot and my laptop will be available get its internet thru the note.

Do you have any information about any issues with hot-spot with note phones? Or is this an issue of the past?

Also, what could be the cause of not-giving-hot-spot access. As far as I remember, I believe USB & Bluetooth options did not work either.

Comment: AFAIK, certain carriers (especially US, and especially Verizon) would make changes to the device software so it prevents hotspot usage when a SIM of different carrier is inserted. I'm thinking you might have fallen victim to this on the Note3. Just buy an unlocked (not locked to carrier) device and you should be fine.

Comment: I think this is a pretty reasonable explanation to this problem. Thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: If you can make clear of the model number of your Note 3, I can judge whether it's a Verizon variant and if I should move the comment to a more concrete answer. Thank you.

Comment: It was an At&T phone. Do you still need the modal number?

Comment: Ah, yes, AT&T also does that provisioning quite often.